# How to use NSUserDefaults in a TableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults

I would like to save data with `NSUserDefaults`. My app consists of a View Controller in which I have a `TableView` with UITextFields. The View Controller has a Save button at the top in Navigation Bar.  The user could edit the UITextFields and then click on Save to save the data.

I would like to have your advices on how to do it. I started something like this : I declare an UITextFields in my .h file like this (just one data for example, but my App has 10 UITextfields) :

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *email;`

and then in my .m file I use a prepareForSegue to save the data when the user clicked on Save button :

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.save) return;
    else
    {
        NSString *userEmail = [self.email text];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:userEmail forKey:@"email"];
        [defaults synchronize];    
        NSLog(@"Data saved");
    }
}
```

I also retrieve my data in ViewDidLoad :

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *userEmail = [defaults objectForKey:@"email"];
self.email.text = userEmail;
```

In the .m file I have a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to display the UITextfield.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if ([indexPath section] < 3) {
        UITextField *playerTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 8, 185, 30)];
        playerTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        playerTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        // First section
        if ([indexPath section] == 0 && [indexPath row] == 0) {
            playerTextField.placeholder = @"Smith";
            playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            [playerTextField setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"email"]];

        }
        if ([indexPath section] == 0 && [indexPath row] == 1) {
            playerTextField.placeholder = @"John";
            playerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            playerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        }

        // Second section
        [... SAME STRUCTURE FOR ALL MY SECTION ...]

        playerTextField.delegate = self;
        [playerTextField setEnabled: YES];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:playerTextField];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

So my question is how to assign the first UITextfield to my email NSString? Is that a correct way to proceed like this?

---

Solved: I found a dirty solution... I made a UITextField for each row.

Comment: save all the uitextfields in an array and assign the first to email.

Comment: For instance I just want to save one UITextField to verify that the scheme is good. How to assign the first UITextfield to my email NSString ? With StoryBoard it's easy : ctrl + drag on the @property, but here I can't...